# What is causing this white space at the bottom of my page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, hosting, whitespace, removing-whitespace, shockwave

I've been working on my new website for many days (building it locally on my Macbook Air), and always testing it locally in the Chrome browser on my computer.  When I view it locally, it looks perfect.  However, when I upload it to my hosting account @ hostmonster.com, for some reason it gains this extra white-space at the bottom of the page.  This white space does not appear when I view it locally, even using the exact same browser.

Here's the website uploaded to my hostmonster account: http://happify.org/chesslessonsNEW03/

I've tried searching through stackoverflow and google in general, and I haven't found any answer to this specific question.

I tried looking at the chrome developers' console and the white space was not included in the body, nor in the html tag.  It appears to be *outside* of the html document.  In Chrome developers' console it says something about "shockwave flash" at the bottom of the page where the white space is... I don't know what that is, I didn't put it there, and I'm assuming right now that it's put in there by hostmonster.  I'm not sure if that's what's causing the white space but I just wanted to point it out just in case.

Please let me know if you figure out what's causing this white space and how to get rid of it!

Thanks!

Namaste.

Comment: It might be an extension that is causing it. I just tried it with Chrome 40 Mac and looks fine to me. No white space.

Comment: awesome!  you were totally right, i turned off all my extensions and it fixed the problem.  i wish you had posted as an answer so i could give you an up-vote :-)

Comment: Just added a quick answer :p. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a 3rd party extension that is causing it as they can modify the look and behavior of the page.

You may want to try disabling the extensions for the time being to see if it is causing the issue.

Comment: haha tried to upvote and found out i don't have enough reputation :-\  oh well.  maybe next time